# Connecting to microsoft sql server using php

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to connect to a mssql server using php. The sql server is on a different machine in the network and I have XAMPP installed in my machine. I don't have microsoft sql installed in my server.

I have downloaded the sqlsrv drivers for PHP and then in my php.ini file added the extension `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` under windows extension.

Added the `php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` file inside the `php\ext\` folder of my XAMPP installation.

After restarting apache `phpinfo();` shows that the sqlsrv driver is enabled

```
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql, sqlite, sqlsrv
```

This is my code

```
<?php
$serverName = "192.168.100.102, 1433";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"ATP", "UID"=>"raihan", "PWD"=>"temp123#");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

But on executing I get this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\database\index.php on line 4

Why this error? And how do I go about connecting to mssql server using php?

Comment: php_**pdo**_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll this looks like an extension to PDO, not a set of standalone functions. I believe the extension you must load is `php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll`, following the example of this similar quesiton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776078/cannot-call-function-sqlsrv-connect

Comment: @Havenard I have followed the manual given here http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`php\etc\` sounds like wrong folder, try put in `php\ext\` folder

Note `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` is used by PDO class

1. Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
2. Select download by your PHP version:

   - Select `SQLSRV30.EXE` if use `SQL Server 2005`
   - Select `SQLSRV31.EXE` or `SQLSRV31.EXE` if use `SQL Server 2008`
3. After download, extract dlls
4. If you use php with ThreadSafe (apache2handler -- more probable) copy `php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` fot `ext` folder

For use `sqlsrv` uncomment (or put) this line in php.ini `extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` (or `extension=php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll` for no-thread-safe)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo it has been saved inside the `ext` folder and I have also uncommented the `extension=php_pgsql.dll` but I still get the same error

Comment: There is no such lines in my php.ini is it ok if I go ahead and add those lines by myself?