# XAMPP installation Apache Not Running, Not a Port 80 Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

So I installed XAMPP a long time ago to put WordPress on it. I'm a beginner theme developer and I created a customized theme on this server.

Somehow, out of nowhere, XAMPP's apache won't start up. I've tried the cmd -> net stop was /y running on admin permissions to stop any other applications from using port 80. I checked Skype and changed the port number. I'm not sure what the issue is, I need to have it running so I can work on theme development. Here is my error log:

[Tue Jul 01 12:10:20.677728 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5436:tid 252] AH01909: http://www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

http://www.mediafire.com/view/9714kc20jn4gn05/apache_error.txt

Is there like a resource to diagnose/avoid these errors? I'm trying to get really into Wordpress theme development again but I seem to be more troubleshooting than plain coding/designing. Anyways, thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd be better off over at http://serverfault.com with this type of question.

Comment: it looks like whatever port apache is listening to is in use, its not just skype that uses port 80, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440727/apache-shutdown-unexpectedly

Comment: Thank you, and no I've changed the port numbers in the config files before. And I guess I'll be at serverfault.com.